# Find the first word that occurs twice in a string

Tags: python

Given a string

```
s = "dog cat bat cat dog dog"
```

Find the first word that occurs twice. Answer: cat

So far I have the following code:

```
def first_word(string):
    for word in string.split():
        print(word)

first_word("dog cat bat cat dog dog")
```

Comment: Right now you're just printing each word in the string. How are you going to keep track of which words have already occurred?

Answer (score 2):

First, your function name isn't very descriptive. I would change it to `first_repeated_word`.

The splitting part is good but you need to remember which words you've already seen. Adding the words to a `set` (because it supports fast lookups) and looking if you already seen it would work:

```
def first_repeated_word(string):
    processed = set()
    for word in string.split():
        if word in processed:
            # this will immediatly end the function and return the repeated word
            return word  
        # Add the word to the set.
        processed.add(word)  
    # You need to consider the case when no repeated word was found, best
    # to throw an exception
    raise ValueError('no repeated word found')
```

And the actual test of the function:

```
>>> first_repeated_word("dog cat bat cat dog dog")
'cat'
```

---

I actually have a third party module that does this (a bit more efficiently): [`iteration_utilities.duplicates`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/duplicates.html)

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import duplicates
>>> your_string = "dog cat bat cat dog dog"
>>> next(duplicates(your_string.split()))
'cat'
```

Comment: Since you have a `return` in the `if`, you can drop the `else`

Comment: You're right, how could I have missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just need your loop to check whether you've seen that word before. Something like this:

```
def first_repeat(string):
    previous = []
    for word in string.split():
        if word in previous:
            print(word)
            break
        else:
            previous.append(word)
```

Explanation: For each word, check whether you've seen it before (is it in `previous`), if it *is*, print the word and stop the loop, if it *isn't*, add the current word the list of previous words.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> found_twice = False
>>> seen = set()
>>> i = 0
>>> s = s.split()
>>> s
['dog', 'cat', 'bat', 'cat', 'dog', 'dog']
>>> while not found_twice:
...     if s[i] not in seen:
...         seen.add(s[i])
...     else:
...         print(s[i])
...         found_twice = True
...     i += 1
... 
cat
```

Or:

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> for x in s:
...     if x not in seen:
...         seen.add(x)
...     else:
...         print(x)
...         break
...     
... 
cat
```

There are *lots* of ways to iterate over a sequence of elements and keep track of what you've already "seen."

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
def find_first_duplicate(s):
    s_list = s.split(' ')  # split string everytime there is a space
    l = []
    for item in s_list:
        if item in l:
            # We found the first duplicate!
            return item
        else:
            # Otherwise add to list and try again
            l.append(item)
    return 'No Duplicates'
```

Answer (score 0):

This works out

```
def first_word(string):  # string is the words you pass
    a= string.split()    # a is the list of individual words
    b=[]                 # b is an empty list  
    for item in a:
        if item not in b:
            b.append(item) # here we add unique words to b
        else:       # if a word gets repeated for the first time it will print the word 
            print item
            break          # since we printed the first repeated word we break out of loop

first_word('cat dog bird cat dog')
```

solution :

```
cat
```